# How do I merge 2 HTML documents and their styles correctly?

Tags: html

I'm the author of an email client and one of things I'm in the process of doing is adding support for HTML editing. The editor itself it build upon a HTML rendering control that I've written from scratch, however it supports most HTML and CSS fairly well. The issue I'm having is formatting the reply to HTML email with the user's reply template, which is also HTML (with a different style sheet). So cleanly merging two HTML documents with their own styles without either of them being messed up by the other document's styles.

When the user replies to a HTML email, I parse out the content of the  tag and put it into a  that forms part of the reply. That div's style shows a line down the left margin to inform the user that it's quoting the original email. Gmail does the same thing. Anyway the styles from the HTML block as saved separately and then insert into the head part of the new document.

What happens of course is that if the original email defined a style for say a link, that style affects all the links outside the original quoted area. So things like my signature at the bottom and the From/To header rendering that is part of the reply template all get that styling from the source HTML.

I'm wondering if there is an easy straight forward solution to containing all the original styles to just the quoted part of the document? Something like namespacing? Or limited scope styling?

Comment: Only thing that would come to mind is scoped styles, but browser support for that is rather poor, http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped Apart from that, you might have to modify the style sheet rules by adding an ancestor element to each, so that they are only applied below certain elements.

Comment: I'm already parsing the CSS and converting any body styles to div.scribe_reply (the quoting div) so that's a fairly reasonable extension of that. And the control does support the descendant CSS operator... hmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come to is to add all the incoming styles from the multiple documents to a global style sheet. Styles are matched by first checking the count of properties is the same, then enumerating each property and comparing it's value. This basically gives the software a minimum number of styles to correctly render the content. It could be really slow in a pathological case but so far it's working well in practice.

As an aside, recently I've noticed a lot of email clients striping all the style out of replies. Which to be honest seems like the cheap and nasty solution to the issue. Even if it does give a consistent look.